# How to position virtual objects in specific places in a scene without a marker?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, arcore

I have a question about using ARcore.
How could one develop an app that recognizes the environment and distributes certain virtual elements to specific places in the scene? For example, when viewing a hallway with a few doors, a ladder and an exit, the app places a virtual board (sign) over the ladder with the word 'ladder' written upon it; upon each door, a board with the name of the room and a board saying 'output' on the exit. Is this possible? It is not a GeolocationApp, because GPS would not be used. wanted to do this from the recognition of the environment.
Even with Vuforia I found it difficult to do so, and so far I have not.
Can someone help me? Is there a manual or tutorial about it? Preferably not on video.
I thank everyone.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Comment: Please don't make more work for people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 2):

## You will not go to space today

You want to do something that virtually no software can do yet. The *only* system I've seen that can do anything even *remotely* close to what you want is the Microsoft Hololens. And even it *can't do what you're asking.* The hololens can only identify the *physical shape* of the environment, providing details such as "floor like, 3.7 square meters" and "wall like, 10.2 square meters," and it does so in 8 cm cube increments (any given cube is updated once every few minutes).

On top of that, you want to identify "doors." Doors come in all shapes and sizes and in different colors. Recognizing each door in a hallway and then somehow identifying each one with a room number from a camera image? Yeah, no. We don't have the technology to do that yet, not outside Google Labs and Boston Dynamics.

You will not find what you are looking for.

Comment: But then, how do indoor mapping apps with augmented reality work? Because the GPS signal does not work inside buildings. How can they make it work? Some airports around the world and malls already use this technology. I do not need the same because I will not use the navigation. My idea is to visualize a still, motionless scene.

Comment: indooratlas.com uses a radio technology for location. Yes, it is one of the possibilities, but not the only one. Particularly I know this area well and I know what I'm talking about. The solution I'm looking for is not out of reality, it's more real than imagined, I've only ever manipulated the programming part. But thanks for trying to help.

Comment: The way you have described what you are trying to do borders on technology that is not readily available. The solutions you've seen may involve utilizing features you do not have access to (e.g. radio beacons) or are proprietary software solutions written by hundreds of developers or only work in that specific space.

Comment: I find it interesting you ask if it is possible... then when someone answers it isn't possible you claim you know what your talking about and there are several solutions for it...

Comment: @Eddge It is not possible with off-the-shelf solutions that are available to everyone. The asker has tagged their quesiton with ARCore and Vuforia, neither of which can do this.

Comment: @Draco18s I believe it, it would take a lot of memory to make something like this possible, not to mention all the algorithms involved, image lookups to try and relate what the camera is seeing to what it could possibly be.  BTW my last comment was aimed at the asker.